# How to drag and drop HTML table rows between two tables using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

There are two table components in the code with same number of columns. Need to move row from One table to Another table using Drag and Drop.

Example:

Table 1:

```
<table className='table1'>
<thead>
<tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
<tr><th>Col 3</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Table 2:

```
<table className='table2'>
<thead>
<tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>2</td><td>23/td></tr>
<tr><th>Col 4</th><th>Col 23</th></tr>
<tr><th>Col 5</th><th>Col 32</th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Table 1 and Table 2 need to be drag and droppable. Can anyone help regarding this?

Here is the code, I'm trying to fetch some data from JSON file. Tables are filled by the data, I can drag within the tables, when I drag and drop to another table, I can't move the row to another table, but both are Drag and Droppable. There are no errors shown, when doing drag and drop.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { DragDropContext, Draggable, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import userdata from "./tempData.json";
import user2data from "./tempData_2.json";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(userdata.data);

  const [userrs, setUserrs] = useState(user2data.data);

  const handleDragEnd = (e) => {
    if (!e.destination) return;
    let tempData = Array.from(users);
    let [source_data] = tempData.splice(e.source.index, 1);
    tempData.splice(e.destination.index, 0, source_data);
    setUsers(tempData);
  };

  const handleDraggEnd = (e) => {
    if (!e.destinationn) return;
    let temppData = Array.from(userrs);
    let [sourcee_data] = temppData.splice(e.source.index, 1);
    temppData.splice(e.destinationn.index, 0, sourcee_data);
    setUserrs(temppData);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App mt-4">
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
        <table className="table borderd">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th />
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <Droppable droppableId="droppable-2">
            {(provider) => (
              <tbody
                className="text-capitalize"
                ref={provider.innerRef}
                {...provider.droppableProps}
              >
                {users?.map((user, index) => (
                  <Draggable
                    key={user.name}
                    draggableId={user.name}
                    index={index}
                  >
                    {(provider) => (
                      <tr {...provider.draggableProps} ref={provider.innerRef}>
                        <td {...provider.dragHandleProps}> = </td>
                        <td>{user.name}</td>
                        <td>{user.age}</td>
                        <td>{user.gender}</td>
                      </tr>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
                {provider.placeholder}
              </tbody>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </table>
      </DragDropContext>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDraggEnd}>
        <table className="table borderd">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th />
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        
          <Droppable droppableId="droppable-1">
            {(provider) => (
              <tbody
                className="text-capitalize"
                ref={provider.innerRef}
                {...provider.droppableProps}
              >
                {userrs.map((user, index) => (
                  <Draggable
                    key={user.name}
                    draggableId={user.name}
                    index={index}
                  >
                    {(provider) => (
                      <tr {...provider.draggableProps} ref={provider.innerRef}>
                        <td {...provider.dragHandleProps}> = </td>
                        <td>{user.name}</td>
                        <td>{user.age}</td>
                        <td>{user.gender}</td>
                      </tr>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
                {provider.placeholder}
              </tbody>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </table>
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: That's gonna be extremely time-intensive to get right by hand. Probably best to use an existing tool. react-dnd and react-draggable are both respectable drag/drop libraries for react. I don't know if either specifically does tables.

Comment: @samuei Hi mate, I have updated my working code, can you help with that?

Comment: Sorry. I don't have experience with that library, but you could edit your post to add relevant tags. That might help you find people who do. You might also want to give more information than "it is not working as expected" so nobody closes it for being too vague.